# Angular 7 - Nested <ng-template> label doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-ng-if, ng-template

I have this code as follow:

```
<h2>{{ commentTitle }}</h2>

<div *ngIf="errorHappened; then displayError else displayComments">
  <div *ngIf="comments == undefined || comments.length == 0; then noComments else commentsList"></div>
</div>

<ng-template #displayError>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">An error has occurred. Please try again.</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #displayComments>
  <ng-template #commentsList>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let comment of comments">
        <div>{{ comment.user }}</div>
        <div>{{ comment.date }}</div>
        <div>{{ comment.content }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #noComments>
    <div>No comments yet</div>
  </ng-template>
</ng-template>

<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openDialog()" mat-raised-button type="button">Add new comment</a>
```

Could anyone help me about why the nested div's after h2 label doesn't work please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add details on _specifically how_ it "doesn't work": any errors in the console? What happens when you build with `--aot`? [ask]

Comment: Is this question even about the <ng-template> tag? Your question is about the <div> and <h2> tags not the <ng-template> tag.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as follows:

```
<h2>{{ commentTitle }}</h2>

<div *ngIf="errorHappened; then displayError else displayComments"></div>

<ng-template #displayError>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">An error has occurred. Please try again.</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #displayComments>
  <div *ngIf="comments == undefined || comments.length == 0; then noComments else commentsList"></div>
  <ng-template #commentsList>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let comment of comments">
        <div>{{ comment.user }}</div>
        <div>{{ comment.date }}</div>
        <div>{{ comment.content }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #noComments>
    <div>No comments yet</div>
  </ng-template>

  <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openDialog()" mat-raised-button type="button">Add new comment</a>
</ng-template>
```